# Unable to Install Microsoft Office 2010 on Ubuntu 17.04 With PlayOnLinux

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am running a x86_64 desktop with Ubuntu 17.04, and am attempting to install Microsoft Office 2010 Home and Student, 64 bit. When I attempt to install the program, I get the following errors

```
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x6a07afa1, context 0xa33ca8, init_notify 0, handle 0x130e7d4): stub
fixme:iphlpapi:CancelMibChangeNotify2 (handle (nil)): stub
err:process:create_process L"C:\\users\\trenton\\Temp\\OWP6164.tmp\\setup.exe" not supported on this installation (x86_64 binary)
[POL_Wine] Error: Wine seems to have crashed
If your program is running, just ignore this message
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 255
[POL_Wine_OverrideDLL] Message: Overriding DLLs
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.7.52 regedit /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/override-dll.reg (Working directory : /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts)
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[POL_Call] Message: Calling POL_Install_msxml6
[POL_Call] Message: ----- Starting function POL_Install_msxml6 -----
[POL_GPG_auth_script] Message: Checking signature of POL_Install_msxml6
[POL_GPG_install_key] Message: Importing PlayOnLinux public key
[POL_Source] Message: POL GPG : Good signature
[POL_Download_Resource] Message: Downloading resource http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/a/f/eafb8ee7-667d-4e30-bb39-4694b5b3006f/msxml6_x86.msi
[POL_SetupWindow_detect_exit] Warning: POL_SetupWindow_detect_exit is deprecated
cat: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//configurations/guis/3754: No such file or directory
[POL_Call] Message: ----- Ending function POL_Install_msxml6 -----
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Looking for <WINWORD.EXE>, found <>
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
[POL_Shortcut] Error: Binary not found: WINWORD.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Shortcut created:  Microsoft Word 2010
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Looking for <EXCEL.EXE>, found <>
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
[POL_Shortcut] Error: Binary not found: EXCEL.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Shortcut created:  Microsoft Excel 2010
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Looking for <POWERPNT.EXE>, found <>
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
[POL_Shortcut] Error: Binary not found: POWERPNT.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Shortcut created:  Microsoft Powerpoint 2010
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Looking for <ONENOTE.EXE>, found <>
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
[POL_Shortcut] Error: Binary not found: ONENOTE.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Shortcut created:  Microsoft OneNote 2010
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Looking for <OUTLOOK.EXE>, found <>
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
wrestool: /home/trenton/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
[POL_Shortcut] Error: Binary not found: OUTLOOK.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

As you can see, the trouble lies with wine crashing. I read that I need to install wine:i386, but when i attempt to do so, I get the following output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine:i386 : Depends: wine64:i386 (>= 1.6.2-20) or
                      wine32:i386 (>= 1.6.2-20) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I attempt to install either of those, I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'wine64' instead of 'wine64:i386'
wine64 is already the newest version (1.8.7-1ubuntu1).
```

It's the same for wine32:i386. Is there any way to prevent it from defaulting to the amd64 version of wine64/wine32?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have 64-bit ubuntu you need the 64-bit packages. currently wine's 64-bit isn't as strong as 32-bit.  I recommend making a 32-bit prefix and attempting to install Office 2007 32-bit. Also, I recommend searching http://winehq.org for a configuration guide.

Comment: You can never "legally" activate MS Office 2010 AFAIK installed with Wine so I suggest to use a VBox with Windows running as your Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you install PlayOnLinux (`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`) and then use that to install Microsoft Office. PlayOnLinux solves your problem because it allows you to select from, and install, numerous versions of Wine (both x86 and amd64) and then use them with different programs.

For example, within PlayOnLinux I have installed Wine x86 versions 2.22, 2.1 and 1.7.52. See here:

[image: Screenshot from PlayOnLinux]

Within PlayOnLinux I have 5 programs installed. Currently they are all using Wine version 2.22 but I could set it so each of them uses a different version if I wanted/needed to.